.d.ts en express no me toma los nuevos campos
Estoy intentando extender mi Request de express para poder agregarle un objeto user en el que voy a agregarle datos de logueo que voy a recuperar del token de JWT pero para hacer todo mas simple y no tener que decodificar el token muchas veces me gustaria agregarlos desde un middleware y solamente acceder a sus datos el problema es que cuando quiero levantar la app estoy teniendo este error:

En mi codigo tengo este d.ts:
declare namespace Express {
interface Request {
    User: {
      IdWeb: string | null;
      Email: string | null;
      Vencimiento: Date | null;
    }
  }
}

Y desde el codigo al intentar acceder a el no tengo error sino al intentar ejecutar la app en node.
Este es parte de mi tsconfig.json
"typeRoots": [
    "./node_modules/@types",
    "./config/@types/express"
  ]

Les dejo el middleware donde se guardan los datos.
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import jwt, { JwtPayload } from 'jsonwebtoken';

export const addUserToRequest = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    const authHeader = req.headers['authorization'];

    if (authHeader) {
      const token = authHeader.replace('Bearer ', '');

      try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRETKEY!) as JwtPayload;

        req.User = req.User || { IdWeb: null, Vencimiento: null, Email: null };

        const fechaVencimiento = decoded.Vencimiento;
        if(!fechaVencimiento){
          req.User.Vencimiento = new Date(decoded.Vencimiento);
        }

        req.User.IdWeb = decoded.IdWeb ?? null;
        req.User.Email = decoded.Email ?? null;        
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error decodificando el token:', error);
      }
    } else {
      console.warn('No se encontró el header de autorización');
    }

    next();
  }catch(error){
    throw error;
  }
}

Y aca es donde quiero acceder:
export const createGasto = async (req: Request<CreateGastoRequest>, res: Response) => {
    try{
        const request = req.body;
        const idUsuario = req.User.IdWeb; // En esta linea intento acceder al objeto
        
        if(!idUsuario)
            throw 'Usuario no especificado.';

        const user = await getUserByIdWeb(idUsuario);

        if(!user)
            throw 'Usuario no encontrado';

        const nuevoGasto: GastoEntity = {
            descripcion: request.Descripcion,
            descripcionlarga: request.DescripcionLarga,
            idtipogasto: request.IdTipoGasto,
            fechaCreacion: new Date(),
            fechaVencimiento: new Date(request.FechaVencimiento),
            monto: request.Monto,
            idestadogasto: EstadoGasto.Impago,
            idusuario: user!.id,
            idWeb: newGuid()
        }

        const gastoCreado = await crearGasto(nuevoGasto);

        res.status(201).json({message: 'Gasto creado exitosamente.', gasto: gastoCreado});

    }catch(e){
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error al crear el gasto', details: e });
    }
}


Por favor, ¿podrías compartir el código completo y no solo el trecho para una mejor evaluación del problema...?

Comparte más el código, me parece que algo no está bien detrás de esto.

@cardosource ya actualice la pregunta con mas código.

Por curiosidad en el archivo que programo .. export const createGasto , ¿dónde persiste el error colocó los imports??? ¿colocó el import import { Request, Response } from 'express'; ???

@cardosource si, están los import que nombraste en la primer linea del documento

Qué pasa si agregar el operador ? donde te da el error? const idUsuario = req.user?.IdWeb;

Perdón por la ausencia, copié todo el código y lo coloqué en el mismo directorio y compiló sin errores, y también probé cada .ts en directorios diferentes y todo sin error. Probé usando tsc-w en cada archivo y tuve el mismo error que informaste. Probé con tsc -w archivo.ts y ocurrió el error de "Property 'User' does not exist on type", pero cuando uso el tsc -w de forma global no ocurre ningún error, incluso en archivos en directorios separados. Solo usando el tsc -w.
